# Dataflow JDBCIO Read with Generic Row Mapper

Tags: java, jdbc, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using a Dataflow job to read from a MS-SQL database and write the results to a Big Query table. The purpose of the Dataflow job is to be able to create tables with different schemas based on whatever query was run. I can't find a way to set up a generic Row Mapper when doing the JDBCIO read, and was hoping there was a standard way to create a row to write to Big Query based on the schema of the rows returned in the JDBCIO.read ResultSet.

I get the following error when I don't include the RowMapper in my query definition:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: withRowMapper() is required  at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Read.expand(JdbcIO.java:810)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Read.expand(JdbcIO.java:711)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:548)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:192)
    at edu.mayo.mcc.aide.sqaTransfer.SqaTransfer.buildPipeline(SqaTransfer.java:81)
    at edu.mayo.mcc.aide.sqaTransfer.SqaTransfer.main(SqaTransfer.java:66)
```

I am trying to writeandrea based on the following setup:

```
PCollection<TableRow> results = pipeline
        .apply("Connect", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(buildDataSourceConfig(options, URL))
                .withQuery(query)
                .withRowMapper("WHAT NEEDS TO BE HERE TO CREATE A GENERIC ROW MAPPER"));

results.apply("Write to BQ",
        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(dataset)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my solution for a somewhat similar case. If you are using beam in GCP's Dataflow, you can create so-called Flex-template, which allows to dynamically build "pipeline graph" based on input parameters. So by extending DataflowPipelineOptions interface you can specify your own parameters that you will set during job creation stage.

```
    @Description("List of Tables and corresponding columns to partition by (format: TABLENAME:PARTITIONCOLUMN;TABLENAME:PARTITIONCOLUMN)")
    String getTableNames();

    void setTableNames(String value);
}
```

Then by using readWithPartitions() (which essentially just makes a series of paginated queries by column you specify withPartitionColumn) you could call withRowOutput() from which during next step of writing to bq it can infer a schema from beam by calling .useBeamSchema().

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JDBCToBQPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
        .as(JDBCToBQPipelineOptions.class);
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    Set<SchemaUpdateOption> schema_options = Set.of(SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
        SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION);

    for (String table : options.getTableNames().split(";")) {
      String[] tableMeta = table.split(":");// tableMeta[0] is tableName, tableMeta[1] is column to partition query by

      PCollection<GenericRecord> records = p.apply(
          JdbcIO.<GenericRecord>readWithPartitions()
              .withDataSourceProviderFn(JdbcIO.PoolableDataSourceProvider.of(
                  JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create({DRIVER CLASS NAME HERE}, {JDBC_URL_HERE})
                      .withUsername({USERNAME HERE})
                      .withPassword({PASSWORDHERE})
                      .withConnectionProperties({CONNECTION PROPS HERE})))
              .withTable(tableMeta[0])
              .withPartitionColumn(tableMeta[1])
              .withNumPartitions(options.getNumPartitions())
              .withRowOutput()
      // step 2 write to BigQuery
      );
      records.apply(
          BigQueryIO.<GenericRecord>write()
              .to({YOUR BQ DESTINATEION HERE}+"."+tableMeta[0])
              .withExtendedErrorInfo()
              .useBeamSchema()
              .withSchemaUpdateOptions(schema_options)
              .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
              .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
    }
    p.run();
  }
```

Make sure that during Flex template creation you specify
`ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS` and `ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_CLASSPATH` in your docker file that you would build an image from and `COPY target/YOURJARNAME.jar ${FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_CLASSPATH}`to make sure that fat/uber jar is packaged.
Fat jar can be generated by running `mvn clean package` and having maven-shade-plugin included in your pom.xml plugin configs

Comment: Alternatively - you can lookup a "generic" mapper implementation from google right here, this is repo with google-provided template samples. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/8dd485db028c2313ebfd332ef8607810d1f3640c/v1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/common/JdbcConverters.java

Answer (score 0):

In the read part you can use `TableRow` with `JdbcIO` as follow :

```java
PCollection<TableRow> results = pipeline
        .apply("Connect", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(buildDataSourceConfig(options, URL))
                .withQuery(query)
                .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<TableRow>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableRow mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) {
                        // Implements your logic here.
                      
                        return tableRow;
                    }
                )
        );
```

I think `Dataflow` isn't the easier service to meet your need because you have to pass a schema to `BigQueryIO` to allows `Dataflow` to create the table with `CREATE_IF_NEEDED` option.

The schema is passed with the following method : [withSchema(schema)](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/), example :

```java
  rows.apply(
        "Write to BigQuery",
        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
            .to(String.format("%s:%s.%s", project, dataset, table))
            .withSchema(schema)
            // For CreateDisposition:
            // - CREATE_IF_NEEDED (default): creates the table if it doesn't exist, a schema is
            // required
            // - CREATE_NEVER: raises an error if the table doesn't exist, a schema is not needed
            .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            // For WriteDisposition:
            // - WRITE_EMPTY (default): raises an error if the table is not empty
            // - WRITE_APPEND: appends new rows to existing rows
            // - WRITE_TRUNCATE: deletes the existing rows before writing
            .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));

    // pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
  }
```

That means in your case, you have to build the schema from the current `TableRow` in the `PCollection`.

It's not easy to do that with `Beam`.
It would have been easier if you could have used a schema for your BigQuery table.

I propose you another solution and approach :

- Export the `MS-SQL` data to `Cloud Storage`
- Import the `Cloud Storage` files to `BigQuery` with `autodetect` mode to infer the schema from the file.

You can add this logic in a `Shell` script if you want to automate this process with `gcloud` cli.

Example to [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data) `GCS` file to `BigQuery` :

```bash
 bq load \
    --autodetect \
    --replace \
    --source_format=CSV \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.csv
```